# Python unicode trouble

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.6

I am having trouble with unicode in a script I am writing. I have scoured the internet, including this site and I have tried many things, and I still have no idea what is wrong.

My code is very long, but I will show an excerpt from it:

```
raw_results = get_raw(args)
write_raw(raw_results)
parsed_results = parse_raw(raw_results)
write_parsed(parsed_results)
```

Basically, I get raw results, which is in XML, encoded in UTF-8. Writing the RAW data has no problems. But writing the parsed data is. So I am pretty sure the problem is inside the function that parses the data.

I tried everything and I do not understand what the problem is. Even this simple line gives me an error:

```
def parse_raw(raw_results)
    content = raw_results.replace(u'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>', u'')
```

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position
>   570: ordinal not in range(128)

Ideally I would love to be able to work with unicode and have no problems, but I also have no issue with replacing/ignoring any unicode and using only regular text. I know I have not provided my full code, but understand that it's a problem since it's work-related. But I hope this is enough to get me some help.

**Edit:** the top part of my parse_raw function:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import XML, fromstring, tostring
def parse_raw(raw_results)    
    raw_results = raw_results.decode("utf-8")
    content = raw_results.replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>', '')
    content = "<root>\n%s\n</root>" % content
    mxml = fromstring(content)
```

**Edit2:**: I think it would be a good idea to point out that the code works fine UNLESS there are special characters. When it's 100% English, no problem; whenever any foreign letters or accented letters are involved is when the issues arise.

Comment: I suspect your problem is in `get_raw()` - how are you reading the file?

Comment: `get_raw()` is no problem because `write_raw()` is working fine, the problem is always in `write_parsed()` which gets the data after it goes through the `parse_raw()` function

Comment: This is most probably where you're wrong. The problem occurs when you're mixing encoded and non-encoded strings. As long as you read and write using the same kind of string, you won't notice the problem. As soon as you start using the data as in your `parse_raw()`  function, you will.

Comment: so how do i edit and work with the data so that it stays in the same encoding?

Comment: As I said, you need to show us how you're reading the file. All else is guesswork (as you can see below).

Comment: im not reading a file, im querying a server and getting an XML result. and then i am simply writing it to a file. and THEN i am modifying/parsing it, and then when i want to write again is the error... i dont see how the source has the problem, the problem is obviously in my function.

Comment: In your edit: is `data` supposed to be `raw_results`?

Comment: corrected. sorry, i changed the name here to be more clear.

Comment: In that case, use `raw_results.replace(u'...',u'')`. The `u`s are important! The `raw_results.decode('utf-8')` line makes `raw_results` a `unicode`. `X.replace(Y,Z)` works best when `X`, `Y`, `Z` are all of the same type.

Comment: now my error is on the last line `mxml = fromstring(content)` saying: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf3' in position 5457: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: `fromstring` expects a `str`, not `unicode`. Does `fromstring(get_raw(args))` raise an exception, or is the original XML parsable by `fromstring`?

Comment: so is there any builtin python xml parser that can support unicode?

Comment: All XML parsers deal with unicode aka utf-8...strange question

Comment: Don forget to read this before proceeding further:http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: On your snippets above, in your "parse_raw" function you _decode_ the (supposidleyy utf-8) xml string - this yelds an unicode object. On the following line, you treat it as a non unicode, doing a replace and apssing it a string object, not an unicode object. This should not  yield an error per se, but shows you have no ide what you are doing, indeed. Please, just read the URL aI posted above. To the end.

Comment: @jsbueno the decode line was added just now based on unutbu's answer below. not my original code. i have since removes it, and now my code is working perfectly after a few other small tweaks. i will put an answer up soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for the input and the nudges. I have subsequently solved my own problem by going over my code for the millionth time with a fine-toothed comb, and I have found the culprit. And I have solved all my problems now.

For anyone with a similar problem, I have the following information that could help you:

- Use the `codecs` module for writing your files.
- Do not try to handle it all along your code, your code should ignore any type of character set throughout methods, and should have specific methods or calls to methods where only you modify the charset. (this helped me find the problem)

My problem was that at a certain point I was trying to turn unicode into unicode. And in another place I was trying to turn normal ASCII into ASCII again. So whenever I solved one issue, another arose and I figured it was the same problem.

Break your issue into sections... and then you might find your problem!

Answer (score 3):

`raw_results` is probably a `str` object, not a `unicode` object.

`raw_results.replace(u'...', ...)` causes Python to first decode the `str` `raw_results` into a `unicode`. Python2 uses the `ascii` codec by default. `raw_results` contains the byte `'\xd7'` at position 570, which is not decodeable by the `ascii` codec (i.e., it is not an ascii character).

Here is a demonstration of how this error might occur:

```
In [27]: '\xd7'.replace(u'a',u'b')      
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Whereas if `raw_results` were unicode, there would be no silent decoding with `ascii`, and therefore no error would occur:

```
In [28]: u'\xd7'.replace(u'a',u'b')
Out[28]: u'\xd7'
```

You can fix this problem by decoding `raw_results` explicitly, provided you know the appropriate codec:

```
raw_results = raw_results.decode('latin-1')
```

`latin-1` is just a guess. It might be correct if the character at position 570 is a multiplication symbol:

```
In [26]: print('\xd7'.decode('latin-1'))
×
```

Comment: its utf-8 . and doing that didnt help. `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2605' in position 5620: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the `raw_results` str around characters 570 and 5620, such as `repr(raw_results[565:575]+raw_results[5615:5625])`?

Comment: cant show you the data - sorry, its sensitive. but the error is `raw_results = raw_results.decode("utf-8")`

Comment: Hmmm. If you are getting a `UnicodeEncodeError` there, then `raw_results` must already be `unicode`...

Comment: Please put us out of our misery and tell us: what is `raw_results`: a `str` or a `unicode`? :)   (i.e., post `type(raw_results)`).

Comment: its a `str` but it should be utf-8 ?

Comment: Are you sure posting 20 bytes of your super sensitive data for us is not possible?